# Realm findAll with case Insensitive on Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have an Contact who have a a colum name, that have names on Lower and upercase. I'd want to findAll with Case.INSENSITIVE and i didn't match any answers. How i should do that?

I'm doing it :

```
realm.where(Contact.class).findAllAsync().sort("name")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm doesn't have a native solution for that question.

I have solved it creating an extra colum with lowerCases "name", and then a sort by lowerCase, like this:

```
realm.where(Contact.class).findAllSortedAsync("lowerCase"));
```

Comment: instead of using findAllAsync() and then using sort() , better use findAllSortedAsync()

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020, Realm does have support for case insensitive queries. I use it in one of my apps and works fine:

```
String searchText = "john"; // Some name
RealmResults<Person> persons = realm.where(Person.class).contains("username", searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE);
```

It'll pull John, JOHN, john, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Case.INSENSITIVE flag is not yet supported for sort method. You should get all results and then sort it manually :

```
RealResults<Contact> list = realm.where(Contact.class)
    .findAll()
    .sort("name");

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
        return c1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not searching for an String, i'm searching for all objects on Contacts. I'd want to put it on adpter.

Comment: So why do you need case insensitive ? just get all.

Comment: it returns first the lowercases in order and after the uppercases in order.

Comment: i found it : https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2970 , doesnt have a native solution for the question

Comment: Yes issue is still open, you'll have to sort result on your own.